# Calling a SOAP Web service using spring integration dsl

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I need to call a SOAP Webservice from my REST service. I'm using Spring integration in my project. Currently I'm using xml based configuration to achieve the target. But I want to write code in java dsl. Kindly help me how to call a SOAP service from a REST Service using Spring integration DSL.

One example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ws.html#webservices-dsl

```java
@Bean
IntegrationFlow outboundMarshalled() {
    return f -> f.handle(Ws.marshallingOutboundGateway()
                    .id("marshallingGateway")
                    .marshaller(someMarshaller())
                    .unmarshaller(someUnmarshalller()))
        ...
}
```

or

```java
.handle(Ws.simpleOutboundGateway(template)
            .uri(uri)
            .sourceExtractor(sourceExtractor)
            .encodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE)
            .headerMapper(headerMapper)
            .ignoreEmptyResponses(true)
            .requestCallback(requestCallback)
            .uriVariableExpressions(uriVariableExpressions)
            .extractPayload(false))
)
```

Comment: Hi @Gary Russel, for Ws what is the package? Because I have Spring-integration and dsl dependency added in my project even though I'm not getting Ws.

Comment: spring-integration-ws see the start of that chapter https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ws.html#ws you don’t need a separate dependency for the dsl, it has been merged into the core project for a long time now,